# Convergence of $\int_0^{\infty}\left(\frac{x}{\ln x}\right)^c\frac{1}{1+x^{4c}}\ dx$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, improper-integrals

For which values of parameter $c\in\mathbb{R}$ is $$\int_0^{\infty}\left(\frac{x}{\ln x}\right)^c\frac{1}{1+x^{4c}}\ dx < \infty$$
Using the inequality $\ln x > \frac{x}{1+x}$ it can be shown that $$\int_0^{a}\left(\frac{x}{\ln x}\right)^c\frac{1}{1+x^{4c}}\ dx < \int_0^{a}\left(\frac{x}{\frac{x}{1+x}}\right)^c\frac{1}{1+x^{4c}}\ dx = \int_0^{a}\frac{(1+x)^c}{1+x^{4c}}\ dx < \infty \ \ \forall c\in\mathbb{R}$$

But I don't know what next, how to nicely check convergence of $$\int_a^{\infty}\left(\frac{x}{\ln x}\right)^c\frac{1}{1+x^{4c}}\ dx$$ is respect to $c$. Got any tips?

Comment: $\ln x > \frac{x}{1+x}$ is true for $x >1.93295$

Comment: You're right, it was $ln(1+x)>\frac{x}{x+1}$ for $x>-1$ without $x=0$

Comment: Fot he integral between $0$ and $\infty$, you have convergence if $c<-2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Around $+\infty$, the integrand behaves like $\frac{x^{c-
4c}}{\ln^{c} x}$ then we need $-3c<-1$ (the P-test) meaning $c>1/3$.

The above condition is necessary, it remains to prove that if $c>1/3$ the integral converges for $a>1$ which is easy.

If $a<1$, we must have $c<1$ due to the singularity around zero.

**Conclusion :** the integral mentioned in the title converge iff $c\in (1/3,1)$.

Comment: Just by curiosity, did you compute the integral for any value of $c$ ? Please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I tried with $c=1$ (wich should be the easiest) and got nothing elementary.

Comment: What did you get as a result for the integral ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Seems like I have done some errors and got a Lerch Phi results, if I get something I'll tell you.

Comment: What did you type nto arrive to something involving Lerch Phi ? Be sure it is just by curiosity. I have the feeling that we need $c<-2$ but I am just unable to prove.

Comment: No, wait, I don't see how the condition for $c$ is necessary here. What about this logarithm expression?

Comment: $\ln x =o(x^{\epsilon})$ for any $\epsilon >0$, so it does not matter.
By the way, for the last integral you need $a>1$ or $c<1$ or else you get $+\infty$, I forgot to mention this.

Comment: @Michael yes but we don't need that, we have stronger condition $c>1/3$.

Comment: Where does $c<1$ stem from?

Comment: @Jules Near $1$ we have $\ln x\sim (x-1)$.